# Python Selenium - StaleElementReferenceException - WebDriverWait doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I'm trying to web scrape some information from a website. The loop works the first time but the 2nd time the error occurs. I've tried several approaches to solve it with implicit wait or WebDriverUntil but the exception continues to appear. Would you give me a hand?

Here is the code:

```
website = 'https://www.elempleo.com/co/ofertas-empleo/55-6-millones?'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)

empleos = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div.result-list.js-result-list.js-results-container')

data = []
i = 0

data = empleos[0].text.splitlines()

while i < 4:
    data.append(empleos[0].text.splitlines())
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")  
    siguiente = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a.js-btn-next')
    siguiente[0].click()
    i += 1
```

I tried using:

`siguiente = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "a.js-btn-next")))`

and

`driver.implicitly_wait(10)` with different times but it didn't work

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a.js-btn-next')` How many of those buttons do you expect to exist?  As far as I can see, this will always find the uppermost one in the whole document, which will always be the same one.  Presumably you intended to search forward from the location of the previous one you found, not search from the top every time.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that there is only one. It is always the same button but in a different page (it is the next button to change page). The error pops up when I run the code in the while loop... If I run it manually it works perfectly but as the loop runs it faster, I think the page hasn't refreshed enterily so it fails